# IE reducing number of windows processes when tab closed

Tags: internet-explorer, memory

In IE version 8/9 (possibly 7 also) when you create a new tab a new Windows process is created.

When you close the tab the process remains.  I'm assuming that IE is reserving the memory as it will be able to use it again next time I open a tab.

I need to find a way to close this process when a tab is closed.

I have an application which uses too much memory per tab.  It's fine until users have opened and closed many tabs.  IE is pretty much sat hogging 300-500Mb of memory with only a couple of tabs open.

This is phase 1 of solving the issue, I'm also going to dig in and reduce the amount of memory the application uses but does anyone know if there is a low level config change which will stop IE from reserving memory?  Possibly a reg edit?

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those processes live for a preset number of seconds before going away, in case you happen to open a new tab right after closing the old one (a common user scenario).  That way IE avoids paying the process-startup tax.

However, you can control the amount of time it waits to shutdown processes using this registry key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"TabShutdownDelay"=dword:00000000
```

For more info, see [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/16/closing-an-ie-8-tab-does-not-immediately-close-the-spawned-iexplore-exe-process.aspx).

Comment: This is just perfect. You have just made my evening. Thank you! You are now a living legend to me. :)

Comment: Do you have any idea what the 'FrameShutdownDelay" registry key does?

Comment: Nope, I got out of the browser plug-in business.